# Engine Assembly Grease - Starting up a Dry/Dormant Engine

Tags: automotive-engineering

I was reading about the purpose of engine assembly grease and apparently it's purpose is to provide the initial lubrication when first starting up the engine until the crankcase oil has time to coat everything.

But how is this any different from starting up a car engine that has been in storage long enough for all the oil to run off the parts? If you need to have a disassembled engine to coat everything inside with assembly grease how come I never hear anything about needing to disassemble a stored engine to lubricate it before starting it up?

Comment: Why would the oil all run off unless you rinsed it with solvent ? Long ago ( like all my comments) I pulled cam shafts from Olds V8 engines in a junkyard. I needed a cam to send for modified regrind . I pulled a few because I had to pull a few before I found one with no worn lobes. All the cams had a film of oil.

Comment: @blacksmith37 If that's the case then that's the reason. You just hear people say that a car in storage for a long time has all sorts of potential maintenance issues and one of the ones is that the oil runs back to the sump.

Comment: @DKNguyen oil does run back into the sump - how else do you get to change it?

Comment: @SolarMike Off the rest of the engine into the sump so you have a dry start if it hasn't been run for too long. Is the intent my of question not getting through?

Comment: @DKNguyen you wrote that oil running back into the sump is an issue - I was pointing out an advantage.

Comment: @SolarMike You're not understanding. The regular degree to which oil drains back into the sump here is irrelevant in the context of the question and I thought that goes without saying. When people talk about oil running back into the sump being a problem for car storage they are talking about *all* the oil (or at least enough of it) drains back into the sump to result in in a dry start.

Comment: @DKNguyen then you have obviously failed to understand my answer and the followup comment.

Comment: @SolarMike What I am looking for is for someone to say dry starts from storage are not a concern because the oil can't ever completely run off the components or to give a reason why you don't need to lube up the engine as thoroughly out of storage as you do during assembly. For example, some people apparently some people just use motor oil instead of assembly grease if they assemble and start the engine in a short period of time, but use grease if assembly takes place over a longer period of time because the oil runs off? Yet no one disassembles and fully lubes up an engine out of storage.

Comment: Think about agricultural machinery;  certain equipment is run for only about 2 months in a year and sits dormant for 10 months.

Comment: @blacksmith37 I did some reading though a lot of farm equipment is diesel powered and the diesel provides more lubrication than gas. There does seem to be gas tractors though and at least some farmers do start up their tractor every month or so or perform similar maintenance. Others don't though.  Does that just means those car people are just paranoid? And perhaps the tractor people too? This seems to be surrounded by what I can only describe as superstition.

Comment: That is wrong. GM made Oldsmobile diesels 1977  for several years. did not go well; one problem , some owners did not change oil as necessary because it was not low. The diesel oil had blown past the rings and collected in the crankcase diluting the lube oil and causing bearing failures because it had poor lubricity.

Answer (score 1):

If I have to start an engine that has been sitting for a long period, then I will remove spark or heater plugs or similar to remove compression and spin the engine over on the starter so the oil pump circulates the oil.

If one takes off the oil cap, it can often be seen when oil has reached the valve gear.

After that, fresh fuel, refit plugs and start then let it idle comfortably.
Do remember to check coolant and belts etc.

However, one trick some do when building new engines is to either fill the oil pump lobe spaces with a light grease to get the pump to pick up oil quicker on initial start. Or another method is to "back-fill" the oil galleries by pumping oil into them again prior to the first start.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking how does that even compare against the initial greasing that the engine gets when disassembled? It feels like that wouldn't be enough because couldn't you just do assemble a new engine first and then do the process you described?

Comment: @DKNguyen when I built my v8’s I used graphite grease on all bearing surfaces during assembly then built the oil pressure up as described anyway. If you want a comparison, build two engines based on the two methods and test - but not sure if you will have comparable or reliable results. Especially when considering servicing intervals and choice of oil quality. I worked at a hydraulics place and motor oil fresh out of the can was rated at 7/10…

Comment: I didn't mean a technical comparison of performance. I meant how come one less extreme method seems to be required in one case but is not sufficient in the other when when they both appear to be very similar scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

The viscosity of grease is much greater than that of engine oil. That means that it will be very difficult to run off.

Some related reading is about the [pitch-drop experiment in Queensland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_drop_experiment). It's a experiment that started in 1927 in Queensland.

[image]

It measures the time between bitumen drops (which are in the order of a decade). Bitumen has a viscocity in the order of million.